# Problema al ejecutar función en Excel

Tags: vba

tengo la siguiente función en VBA para elevar una matriz a la potencia n pero al ejecutarla (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) Arroja error de valor.

Este es el código que llevo actualmente:

```
Function MATRIXPOWER(entrada As Range, n As Integer) As Range
    Dim identity() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    j = 1
    i = 1
    Dim k As Integer
    ReDim identity(entrada.Rows.Count, entrada.Columns.Count)
    For i = 1 To entrada.Rows.Count
        For j = 1 To entrada.Columns.Count
            If i = j Then
                identity(i, j) = 1
            Else
                identity(i, j) = 0
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    Dim inter() As Variant
    ReDim inter(entrada.Rows.Count, entrada.Columns.Count)
    inter = identity
    For k = 1 To n
        inter = Application.MMult(entrada, inter)
    Next k
    MATRIXPOWER = inter
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

No es necesario crear una función para realizar esta operación solo debes utilizar la siguiente **`FormulaArray`**

```
= Rango ^ i
```

*Ejemplo:*
Supongamos que queremos elevar el rango `B2:D6` la potencia `3` mostrando el resultado en el rango `F2:H6`

Entonces introducimos esta **`FormulaArray`** en el rango `F2:H6`

```
=B2:D6^3
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Respecto a la funcion que estas tratando de utilizar toma en cuenta lo siguiente:

El tipo de dato del resultado de la `Function MATRIXPOWER` debe ser `Variant` en lugar de `Range`

Tambien veo que en la `Function MATRIXPOWER` utilizas la función de hoja de trabajo `MMult` sin embargo debes tomar en cuenta que:

> The matrix product array a of two arrays b and c is: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] where i is the
>   row number, and j is the column number.
>
> *La matriz resultante del producto de dos matrices B y C es:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] donde i es el número de línea y j es el número de columna.*

Y no la matriz B elevada a la potencia de la matriz C *(Ver [WorksheetFunction.MMult Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835849(v=office.15).aspx))*.

Answer (score -1):

Puedes intentar lo siguiente:

```
Function matrizpotencia(rango As Range, potencia As Double) As Variant
        Dim i As Integer
    matrizpotencia = rango
    For i = 2 To potencia Step 1
        matrizpotencia = Application.MMult(matrizpotencia, rango)
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: La ejecutas como función matricial Cnt+Shift+Enter